# posting data to asmx page using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, asmx

Greeting,
am trying to post data to asmx webservice using vb.net but am getting the following error "Error WebException The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."

The vb.net coding I used is:

```
Private Function ConnectApi() As String
    Dim hwReq As HttpWebRequest
    Dim hwRes As HttpWebResponse



    Dim gsLogin As String = "xxxxxxx"
    Dim gsPassword As String = "xxxxxxxxx"
    Dim gsCode As String = "xxxxxxxxx"
    Dim mTransactionId As String = "521"
    Dim mBaseCurrency As String = "USD"
    Dim mPaymentValue As Decimal = 2.1
    Dim mDateTime As Date = Now.Date

    Dim mCustomValue As Integer = 15

    'Dim strPostData As String = String.Format("sub={0}&login={1}&password={2}&limit={3}", Server.UrlEncode(ApiSub), Server.UrlEncode(ApiUsername), Server.UrlEncode(ApiPassword), Server.UrlEncode(ApiLimit))
    Dim strPostData As String = String.Format("gsLogin={0}&gsPassword={1}&gsCode={2}&mTransactionId={3}&mBaseCurrency={4}&mPaymentValue={5}&mDateTime={6}&mCustomValue={7}", Server.UrlEncode(gsLogin), Server.UrlEncode(gsPassword), Server.UrlEncode(gsCode), Server.UrlEncode(mTransactionId), Server.UrlEncode(mBaseCurrency), Server.UrlEncode(mPaymentValue), Server.UrlEncode(mDateTime), Server.UrlEncode(mBaseCurrency), Server.UrlEncode(mCustomValue))



    Dim strResult As String = ""
    Try
        'https:/gscash.com/gateway/staging/gsprocess.asmx?wsdl

        hwReq = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://gscash.com/gateway/staging/gsprocess.asmx"), HttpWebRequest)





        hwReq.Method = "POST"
        hwReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        hwReq.ContentLength = strPostData.Length

        Dim arrByteData As Byte() = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strPostData)
        hwReq.GetRequestStream().Write(arrByteData, 0, arrByteData.Length)

        hwRes = DirectCast(hwReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        If hwRes.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            Dim srdrResponse As New StreamReader(hwRes.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8)
            Dim strResponse As String = srdrResponse.ReadToEnd().Trim()

            strResult = strResponse

        End If
    Catch wex As WebException
        strResult = "Error WebException " + wex.Message
    Catch ex As Exception
        strResult = "Error Exception " + ex.Message
    Finally
        hwReq = Nothing
        hwRes = Nothing
    End Try

    Return strResult
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are going about this the hard way.

It would be much, much easier to add the web service as a reference in your application and then access it through direct code rather than trying to build the request/response mechanism yourself. I have verified that the URL you have above can be used to create a web reference in a .Net project.

Please see the following MSDN articles for the exact details on how to add and use these web service references:

[How to: Add and Remove Web References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7ddaa5d-4672-405b-91b3-39de65d7e3a2%28v=vs.90%29)

[How to: Call a Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6e04e02-ed54-47e1-a89e-b90b5eef335d%28v=vs.90%29)

You will see from the second article that once you have the web service reference added, interacting with it is very easy:

```
    Dim oService As New gsCash.gsprocess

    Dim oRequest As New gsCash.PayWithGscash
    oRequest.gsLogin = "login"
    oRequest.gsPassword = "password"

    Dim oResult As gsCash.GsServiceOutput

    oResult = oService.PayWithGscash(oRequest)
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, how to get the oResult displayed so i can read data ?

Comment: If you step through the application in debug mode, you should be able to see the contents of oResult immediately after the call completes. At design time, you should also be able to type oResult. and see a list of the properties available on oResult (such as errDesc, etc).